# Sticky Table Header in overflow parent container with sticky top navigation bar

Tags: html, css, html-table, tailwind-css

I have a table inside a container and want to have the table header to stick below the top navigation (which is sticky as well) on scroll.

I have a Tailwind Playground here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/OYFqCdJR6f

Comment: Your question says one table but in your Tailwind Playground you have two tables, not one. Which one is it?

Comment: @Ken ideally two - or more. But if it makes things more complex, I could get away with one table...

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because both elements, the table header and the navigation are set to `top: 0`. **The top value for the table header must be the same as the navigation height**, in this case 5rem so it can stack right below the navigation, not under it.

I think you also might have to remove `class="overflow-x-scroll"` from the div containing your table.

Here's an example.

```css
th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 5rem;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bg-gray-100 relative pb-20">
  <header class="sticky top-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-300 mb-10 h-20 z-50">Header goes here</header>
  <section class="max-w-xl mx-auto bg-white mb-20">
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
            <th>Sticky Header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sticky Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
            <td>Normal Column</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ken - really appreciate your effort! Unfortunately the horizontal scroll provided by `overflow-x` is required feature that I can not drop. Any chance of getting both to work?

Please also have a look at the CSS tab on the Tailwind playground example. There is a sticky column for horizontal scroll as well.

Comment: +1 I just had this issue and total head scratcher that tailwindcss sticky totally broken when putting `overflow-x-hidden` on my parent container.

Can't exactly figure out how it breaks the sticky so putting this here for the google-fu in case anyone else is having the same problem.